# i have tried using cvCaptureFromCAM for 2.2 and i am told cv::Mat won't work with it

Tags: c++, opencv

If cvCaptureFromCAM is the 2.0-2.1 version of the camera capture then what is the 2.2 version? If this can still work on 2.2 then why am i getting the error? Thank you for you help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[cv::VideoCapture](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are mixing the C++ inteface of OpenCV with the C interface. Choose one of them and stick with it all the way.

On the C interface, `cvCaptureFromCAM()` returns a `CvCapture*` that must be used to retrieve frames through `cvQueryFrame()`, and the this function returns a `IplImage*` not a `cv::Mat`.

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY);

IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
// ... code to process frame ...
```

If you choose the C++ interface, check the reference Martin gave you.